# XAML Button not garbage collected after eliminating references

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I wrote a test program wherein a single `Button` is defined in XAML as the content of a `Window`. Upon the window's loading, the `Button` is programmatically replaced as the window's content, and the field referring to it is also replaced, both by another `Button` which I created programmatically. I thereafter track both `Button` objects using weak references, and poll at 1/10th second intervals the `IsAlive` property of each. Before the first check of `IsAlive` in the first call to the polling method, I wipe out rooting references to the programmatically-defined `Button` as well.

The expectation in running this code would be that, despite nondeterminism in the timing of C# garbage collection, both `Button` objects would eventually be reported as garbage collected. Although the programmatically-defined `Button` shows this behavior, typically within a 1/2 minute, the XAML `Button` is never collected. I've left the program running for more than ten minutes seeing this behavior.

Can anyone tell me why the XAML `Button` object isn't collected? **In particular, I'd like to know where the garbage collection-blocking reference is**, whether it is in my code or it is in the WPF implementation. Perhaps it's in a XAML loading object. Am I looking at some sort of memory leak?

The program described above is included below for reference.

MainWindow.xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="300" Height="150" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Button Name="btn" />
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs :

```
namespace Test {
    public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window {

        private System.WeakReference wr_xamlBtn, wr_programmaticBtn;

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) {

            // Immediately upon the window's loading, create a weak reference to the
            //  button %btn defined in XAML.
            wr_xamlBtn = new System.WeakReference(btn);

            // Replace references in %btn and this.Content to the XAML button with
            //  references to a programmatically-defined button. This would be
            //  expected to free the XAML button for garbage collection.
            btn = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
            Content = btn;

            // Create a weak reference to the programmatically-defined button, so that
            //  when (strong) references to it are removed, it will be eligible for
            //  garbage collection.
            wr_programmaticBtn = new System.WeakReference(btn);

            // Provides a polling mechanism to see whether either the XAML button or
            //  the programmatically-defined button has been collected.
            var dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            dt.Tick += Poll;
            dt.Interval = System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
            dt.Start();
        }

        void Poll(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {

            // If the programmatically-defined button hasn't had its references
            //  removed yet, this does so. This makes it eligible for garbage
            //  collection.
            if (btn != null)
                Content = btn = null;

            // Uses the console to show a timestamp and the state of collection of the
            //  XAML button and the programmatically-defined button.
            System.Console.WriteLine(
                string.Format(
                    "XAML button {0}, Programmatically-defined button {1} @ {2}",
                    wr_xamlBtn.IsAlive ? "Alive" : "Collected",
                    wr_programmaticBtn.IsAlive ? "Alive" : "Collected",
                    System.DateTimeOffset.Now));
        }
    }
}
```

App.xaml :

```
<Application x:Class="Test.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" />
```

Comment: Force a garbage collection for ALL generations. Does this solve the problem ?

Comment: Calling `System.GC.Collect();` within the `Poll(.)` method only had the effect of causing the programmatically-defined Button to be collected right away. I ran the code with this method call added for five minutes but the desired effect on the XAML Button was not produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button is not collected because it was strongly referenced within the Window namescope:

[image: MemProfiler snapshot]

But it shouldn't be recognized as memory leak, because you **should reregister** your new button within the scope:

```
//...
INameScope scope = NameScope.GetNameScope(this);
scope.UnregisterName("btn");
btn = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
Content = btn;
scope.RegisterName("btn", btn);
//...
```